# Images don't load when I add a doctype to my webpage

Tags: html, css, image, doctype

I need to add a `doctype` to my html webpage because IE will only format it correctly if I do so. But when I add it, some images on the page are not loading. The images are embedded with the CSS background property and displayed to the screen in `div`s. It doesn't load the images in all common browsers.

What could be the problem? I really do need the `doctype` up.

CSS:

```css
.blue {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(blue.png) no-repeat center center;
    top: 163;
    width: 228;
    height: 434;
}

.green {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(green.png) no-repeat center center;
    top: 120;
    width: 266;
    height: 209;
}

.orange {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(orange.png) no-repeat center center;
    top: 183;
    width: 165;
    height: 291;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="blue"> </div>
<div class="green"> </div>
<div class="orange"> </div>
```

Doctype at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Most likely you are using some non-standard CSS. Please post small HTML fragment and CSS fragments. Also consider checking console output and styles in dev tools (F12) of browsers you are using to add more details to the question.

Comment: @Derek Added codes. Sorry i thought it might have been an obvious problem, I guess it does need code because of the invalid CSS suggestion

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added the code. The console outputs nothing related to the images or CSS.

Comment: If you right click and inspect your page in Chrome, you can look to see exactly what CSS attributes are being applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with your CSS width and height declarations not having 'px' at the end of it.

Can you check if the `<div>` elements render with a width and height in order to display the background image?

Comment: Bingo. I was being careless and didn't notice. I have never often used doctypes before but thanks for this. Now I know I shouldn't do sloppy coding.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that  is HTML5, which like HTML4 strict requires units on values or else they are ignored. You need to add `px` to the end of all your position height and width numbers.  Alexei is also correct in pointing out that your urls also need to have quotes around them.

Answer (score 0):

Not required, but nice to have: you are missing quotes around Url : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image

```
background: url("orange.png") no-repeat center center;
```

Comment: Even after adding quotes around "url" I am still having no luck.

Comment: I have a similar div for the logo of my website, and it loads fine. Quite a strange error I am haveing.

Comment: I think it has to do with the absolute positioning? that is the only difference between the 3 divs I showed you and the logo CSS

Comment: This answer is not correct -- the quotes for the URI are not required, and omitting them does not cause the image to fail to load in **most** circumstances (like the example in the question): http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri

Comment: -1 withdrawn! Though if I may, the sentence would better read: "Not **required**, but nice to have:". I leave that to your discretion :)